# Fixed side bar on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, sidebar

I am trying to add a script to my page to fix my side bar when the user has reached the bottom of it.

I have tried to add a class to the container of my side bar to fix its position by implementing the script and the CSS below:

**Script**

```
 function fixeSideBar() {
    var myWindow = $( window ),
        mySideBar = $( ".widget-area" );

    myWindow.scroll ( function() {
            if ( myWindow.scrollTop() < 130 ) {
            mySideBar.removeClass( "sticks" );
        } else {
            mySideBar.addClass( "sticks");
        }
    } );
}

$(function() {
        fixeSideBar();
    } );
```

**CSS**

.sticks {
        position: fixed;
        top:-50px;
        float:right;
        left:1000px;
        padding-top:62px;
        width:37%;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        padding-right: 40px;
        padding-left:40px;
    }

However, I am facing two main issues:

1. By adding this new class, I lose the entire formatting of my side bar (which includes its position on the right side of the screen).
2. The entire formatting works fine only on my computer (with a specific screen width and height).

What I would like to accomplish ultimately will be to fix the side bar when the user reaches its bottom (on any type of device), and make sure that the formatting of my side bar stays the same.

Comment: First of all instead of using top and left , use bottom:50px and right:100px or whatever value fit the design , instead of hard coding left 1000px it will not work for smaller device

Comment: use your browser's developer tools to see if it still holds the "widget-area" class .. if it does, then check the CSS (also from the browser's developer tools) to see if there's any properties being over-written by the new class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
myWindow.scroll ( function() {
        if ( myWindow.scrollTop() <= mySideBar.offset().top +mySideBar.height() ) {
        mySideBar.removeClass( "sticks" );
    } else {
        mySideBar.addClass( "sticks");
    }
} );
```

If you want that sidebar to be fixed when bottom of that div is reached you add meSideBar.height() in condition and if you want sidebar to be fixed just as div is shown remove it